# Is there any way to add multiple receivers in Python SMTPlib?

Tags: python, smtplib

I was wondering. Is there any way to add multiple receivers in Python on its default SMTPlib?

Like (subject and content set already, smtp server gmail.):

```
python sendmail.py receiver1@gmail.com receiver2@gmail.com receiver3@gmail.com ...
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Answer (score 8):

Tested before posting!

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.uk.xensource.com')
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'me@example.com'
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(msg.get('From'), recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: This fails when the total characters exceeds 255 in recipients field. The last email address gets trimmed off in the email sent. But the mail will be sent.

Comment: You need to work with send_message instead of sendmail.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail):

> Send mail. The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string,
>   **a list of RFC 822 to-address strings** (a bare string will be treated as
>   a list with 1 address), and a message string.