# Python sendemail() MIMEMultipart not working

Tags: python, email, python-3.4

I have been trying step by step to create a python (v3.4) script to send a email with attachments. I already succesfully send one without attachmente using smtplib library. However, to add an attachment it seems that I need to create an MIMEMultipart object. Nothing weird until here.

Based on examples I created this

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

try:
fromaddr = 'from@email.com'
toaddrs  = ['to@email.com']

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddrs
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'




password = 'ExamplePassword88'

# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(fromaddr,password)


text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, text)
print("Successfully sent email")
```

except SMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
finally:
    server.quit()

However the line **" text = msg.as_string()"** throw me the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/user/upload_file.py", line 37, in 
>      text = msg.as_string()
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email\message.py", line 159, in as_string
>      g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email\generator.py", line 112, in flatten
>      self._write(msg)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email\generator.py", line 192, in _write
>      self._write_headers(msg)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email\generator.py", line 219, in _write_headers
>      self.write(self.policy.fold(h, v))
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email_policybase.py", line 314, in fold
>      return self._fold(name, value, sanitize=True)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\email_policybase.py", line 352, in _fold
>      parts.append(h.encode(linesep=self.linesep,
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `toaddrs` is a list.

You need to have the list of addresses as a string with the addresses separated by commas  e.g.

```
msg['To'] = ",".join(toaddrs)
```

Everything should work fine after that.
See here for more details:
[How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)