# Send email with attachment to a list/array, only getting sent to last person in the list

Tags: python, openpyxl, smtplib

The email is being sent to the last person who doesn't meet the criteria set in the `if`.

I can't understand why it wont send the email to others in the file which meet the criteria.

```
import smtplib, openpyxl, sys from email.mime.multipart 
import MIMEMultipart from email.mime.text 
import MIMEText from email.mime.base 
import MIMEBase from email 
import encoders    
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')    

lastCol = sheet.max_column  
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

unpaidMembers = {}   
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'Y':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = email

fromaddr = "xxx@xxxx.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = email
msg['Subject'] = "Hi"

body = "Hello, This is a test message. Please check attachment"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "xxxxx.pdf"
attachment = open("\\\xxxx.pdf","rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" %  filename)

msg.attach(part)

smtp0bj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtp0bj.ehlo()
smtp0bj.starttls()
smtp0bj.login(fromaddr, 'xxxx')
text = msg.as_string()
smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, email, text)
smtp0bj.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`email` is set to the last value in the for loop and that's why it is only sending the email to last person.

What you should do is create a list of recipients and then use that information:

```
...
...
recipients = []
unpaidMembers = {}   
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'Y':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = email
        recipients.append(email) 

...
...
msg["To"] = ", ".join(recipients)
...
...
smtp0bj.sendmail(fromaddr, recipients, text)
```

Follow the answers in this SO post for more details: [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. However, I don't want to send the mail at once to everyone but one recipient at a time. i.e. one mail per recipient. I will read the thread you have posted.