# Multi-recipient script mail python did'nt work

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have managed to run a python script that will allow me to send mails automatically with an attachment using the cron command; only I would like to use it to send this same mail to several recipients at the same time. This will save me a lot of time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Answer (score 1):

To send the email to multiple users you can include them together in a string with each email seperated by comma. Please try:

```
recipients = ["email1", "email2"]
toaddr = ", ".join(recipients)
```