# how to separate email after fetching from database

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i am fetching email to list from database which is like below

```
'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
```

i want to separate these mail like

```
 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com','XXXXXXXX@gmail.com','XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
```

in python function so can pass it in msg["To"] field.

Comment: `email_list_string.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function with delimeter as `,`:

```
email_string = 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
email_list = email_string.split(",")
```

Comment: but when i am passing this "email_list" variable , it shows error

Comment: Can you provide more details like where are using/passing the "email_list" variable and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) like so

```
'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'.split(',')
```

outputs:

```
 ['XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `msg["To"]` parameter normally takes addresses separated by [comma and a space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12422921/4985733) so the following should be what you need:

```
email_string = 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
msg["To"] = ', '.join(email_string.split(',')
```

This would pass the following single string:

```
XXXXXXXX@gmail.com, XXXXXXXX@gmail.com, XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
```

or alternatively, you could use a replace to add a space:

```
msg["To"] = email_string.replace(',', ', ')
```

If you want your string to have quotes around each email address:

```
email_string = "'{}'".format("','".join(email_string.split(',')))
```

Giving you a string looking like:

```
'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com','XXXXXXXX@gmail.com','XXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
```

Comment: `msg["To"]` does not need space after comma. "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com,XXXXXXXX@gmail.com" would also work.

Comment: Correct, but most examples add the space for clarity.