# Send email to multiple email address using sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, smtplib

```
import sys
import datetime

me = sys.argv[1]
you = sys.argv[2]  #[I want to pass here multiple recipient]
subject = datetime.now().strftime("%I %P")

# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subject headers
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'Status Update ' + str(subject)
msgRoot['From'] = me
msgRoot['To'] = you
#msgRoot['To'] = ",".join(you) 
"""Earlier I was using something like above when I was hardcoding email address insided it"""
```

Can some please suggest what a best way I can use if I need to pass `toaddr` of multiple recipient using `sys.argv`?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I really hope  you have read my question before marking it as duplicate

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I already know how can we send to multiple email using hard coded by sending it sys.arg make things different

Comment: I have read your question, and also answered. Not a dupe? okay, let others decide. reopened

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I am sorry you are correct here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join all addresses using `", "` (comma+space) and command line argument slicing

```
msgRoot['To'] = ", ".join(sys.argv[2:])
```

(adapted from [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib))