# Python - using smtplib to send to multiple recipients

Tags: python, email, pyserial, smtplib

I'm finding it very difficult to modify this code to send to send to multiple recipients, I have tried many variations of the examples already out there. I'm very new to python so any help would be much appreciated.

It is as part of safety system I am designing to alert parents and carers of potential elopement risk for children and adults with ASD.

```
'''
import time
import serial
import smtplib

TO = 'email@mail.org'
GMAIL_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
GMAIL_PASS = 'passowrd'

SUBJECT = 'Security Alert'
TEXT = 'Movement detected!'

ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

def send_email():
print("Sending Email")
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASS)
header = 'To:' + TO + '\n' + 'From: ' + GMAIL_USER
header = header + '\n' + 'Subject:' + SUBJECT + '\n'
print header
msg = header + '\n' + TEXT + ' \n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(GMAIL_USER, TO, msg)
smtpserver.close()

while True:
    message = ser.readline()
    print(message)
    if message[0] == 'M' :
        send_email()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

'''

Send the alert to multiple people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at this yet? [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

It looks like you might be dropping some of the pieces of your header too by overwriting them:

```
header = 'From: ' + GMAIL_USER
```

Instead of:

```
header = header + 'From: ' + GMAIL_USER
```

You might also want to consider using format instead, but I'm already out of my depth on Python :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is actually one of my attempts to fix it, sorry... I've edited back to the working code. I have reviewed but struggling to apply it to this script.