# Multiple recipient is not working in python smtp lib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Im using python 2.7
Im trying to send emails to more than one person. Only one person receives not others.

My code is;

```
import smtplib
import time
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from utilities.ConfigReader import *


def sendEmailNotification(subject, body):
    sender, receiver = getNotificationSettings()
    smtpServer, smtpPort, timeout = getSMTPSettings()
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    R = receiver.split(",")
    body = MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8')
    msg['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = receiver
    msg.attach(body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer, smtpPort)
    server.ehlo()
    try:
        print receiver
        print R
        server.sendmail(sender, R, msg.as_string())
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        time.sleep(float(timeout))
        server.sendmail(sender, R, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

sendEmailNotification("Test","Test")
```

Here R prints;

```
['test@lob.com', 'ratha@lob.com']
```

receiver prints;

```
test@lob.com, ratha@lob.com
```

I followed following thread but didnt work to me;

[How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

What im doing wrong here?

Comment: If `receiver` has a space after the comma how can it be vanished in `R`?

Comment: What is this calling? `getNotificationSettings` in line 10?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. ratha@lob.com is in the list email test@lob.com . So I haven't received the email for `ratha@lob.com` , but received for `test@lob.com` . After changing two private emails, i receive in both emails. So code is working as expected.