# What is the recipient's length in email in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sendmail, mime

I wrote a script in python 3 to send a notification mail to list of stakeholders. I have observed that the last address in the mail received gets trimmed off the moment I give more than 255 characters in the "`To`" field.

**Sample Code:**

```
#me == the sender's email address
me = "myemail@email.com"
#you == the recipient's email address
you = "a1@email.com;a2@email.com;..."
msg['To'] = you
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Test mail"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(messages, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
```

For example, in the **you** field, per**s**on1@email.com, if **s** is the 255th character, then in the output mail, recipients field will be till **pers** from the left, rest gets trimmed off. How to overcome these?

Also, few questions:

- Please provide the RFC or documentation on these. I checked in [rfc822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/). Not much info present.
- Is this related to Mime or smtplib module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib might help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html documentation

Comment: Thanks, for the links, if I use recipients as list and then use the join to make the recipient string, it works. But I want to understand why?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It worked for mail recipient string length <= 255.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using recipients as list and then using the join to make the recipient string works even for characters>=255.

(Use "," instead of "';" as separater)

Syntax that worked for me:

```
you = ["abc@gmail.com", "bcd@gmail.com", ...]
msg["to"] = ",".join(you)
s.send_message(msg)
```