# Is there a way of concatenating emails to multiple recipients via SMTPLib in a Pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, email, smtplib

I have the below code to send  out  emails specific to certain addresses all in a pandas  dataframe. The type says  pandas.series. How can I be able to send each list with multiple addresses? Some have  upto 8 email addresses separated by a semi-colon(;). Only possibility of  sending out  is to a single address. From the below dataframe, I'm able to send emails specific to the  IDs  to  TestEmail values. Nothing works for Emails. I get the below error :

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (421, b'4.7.0 Too many protocol errors (6) on this connection, closing transmission channel.')}
```

**Dataframe df**

```
IDs  CompanyNames     Emails                                        TestEmail
2003    XXX           xx@gmail.com;yy@ryt.com;dd@xx.com;ii@dd.com    kk@kk.com
2004    XXXYY         xx@gmail.com;yy@ryt.com;dd@xx.com              kk@kk.com
2005    XXTTNN        xx@gmail.com;yy@ryt.com;dd@xx.com;ii@dd.com    kk@kk.com
2006    BBOOLL        xx@gmail.com;yy@ryt.com                        kk@kk.com
```

The code is  below. To the single address, I'm able to send  attachments with names matching  df['IDs'] values to the  corresponding  email address.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
import getpass

ids = df['IDs']
emails_to = df['Emails'] #Pandas column with email addresses split  by semi-colon(;)
namesofcompanies  = df["CompanyNames"]
sendfrom  = df["SenderList"]

date_7days = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
date_14days = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

email_pass = input() #Office 365 password 
context=ssl.create_default_context()
for i in range(len(emails_to)): # iterate through the records
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    ID = str(ids[i])
    Emaitstosendto = emails_to[i]
    companynames = namesofcompanies[i]
    tosendfrom = sendfrom[i]
    
    if my_files_dict.get(ID): #Looks for  attachments in the same folder with same name  as the corresponding record 
        smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.office365.com'
        smtp_ssl_port = 587
        email_login = "xxx@xxx.com" #Office 365 email  
        email_from = tosendfrom         
        email_to = Emaitstosendto
        
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = "Received Emails between "+date_7days+" - "+date_14days
        msg['From'] = email_from
        msg['To'] = email_to
        msg['X-Priority'] = '2'    
         
        text = ("XXXX,\n"                
                f"xxxxxx\n\n")
        
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
        filename = my_files_dict.get(ID)#Files in the folder matching the ID   
        fo = open(filename,'rb')

        s2 = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
        s2.starttls(context=context)
        s2.login(email_login, email_pass) 
        attachment = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fo.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
        fo.close()
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)

        msg.attach(attachment)        
        s2.send_message(msg)        
        s2.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from this answer: [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

This is the line you have to change:

First split the email_to into a list of different emails and then join using ", "

```
msg['To'] = ", ".join(email_to.split(";"))
```