# Can't send text email to multiple people, just goes to the first person?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I was having issue's posting on this site so posted on Reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/117uumz/cant_send_text_email_to_multiple_people_just_goes/

However, no one there seems to be able to help.

Kind Regards.

Comment: All relevant information pertaining to your question needs to be included in your post as text, do not link to external sites. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recipients should be a list of strings.

```
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
```

checkout [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for some reason. I also read the link you attached prior to me asking this questions but it was not working for me. I was trying my_list = 'john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk'. Not sure if I did try with brackets or what not but it was not working then. Working now so great, thanks again :)