# How to send html email to multiple recipients using python3 smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send an Email with HTML content to multiple recipients using python-3.10 I have read the documentation and came up with the following code, but, although the email it's been send to all recipients, the message is not showing the html correctly. The message I receive has no html format, nor line breaks. Email text I recive:
[image: Email text]

What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to send an html email message to multiple recipients Here is my code. (I am intensionally hiding the credentials of the server form security reasons)

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid

cobertura = "Movistar"
msisdn="53763615"
client_name="Ernesto Ruiz Rodriguez"
client_document="786876876786786"
mensaje="Este mensaje ha sido enviado a los administradores solamente"
content_text=f"""\
Saludos
El sistema PANIX ha recibido una nueva portabilida móvil inversa con los siguientes datos:
Cobertura: {cobertura}
Msisdn: {msisdn}
Nombre cliente: {client_name}
Documento cliente: {client_document}
Otra información de interes:
{mensaje}
Le recomendamos hacer un seguimiento del estado de esta portabilidad desde el apartado "Portabilidad móvil/Solicitudes portabilidad móvil inversa"
Atentamente:
Equipo Panix
"""

content_html=f"""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<p><strong>Saludos</strong></p>
<p>El sistema PANIX ha recibido una nueva portabilida móvil inversa con los siguientes datos:</p>
<p><strong>Cobertura:</strong> {cobertura}</p>
<p><strong>Msisdn:</strong> {msisdn}</p>
<p><strong>Nombre cliente:</strong> {client_name}</p>
<p><strong>Documento cliente:</strong> {client_document}</p>
<p><strong>Otra información de interes:</strong></p>
<p>{mensaje}</p>
<p>Le recomendamos hacer un seguimiento del estado de esta portabilidad desde el apartado "Portabilidad móvil/Solicitudes portabilidad móvil inversa".</p>
<p>Atentamente:</p>
<p>Equipo Panix</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.server.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('user@server.com','password')

sender_email='from@server.com'
receiver_email='receiver1@gmail.com, receiver2@gmail.com'

message = EmailMessage()
message["Subject"] = "Message with html to multiple receipents"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email

message.set_content(content_text)
message.add_alternative(content_text, subtype='html')

mail.send_message(message)
mail.close()
```

Comment: In your code you're not using `content_html` anywhere after creating it. All the contents are `content_text`. I don't know for sure, but wouldn't you want something along the lines of `message.add_alternative(content_html, subtype='html')` or something like that?

Comment: Are the email contents correct if you only send to one recepient?

You may want to check out this question (if you haven't already):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib

Comment: You where right, I need to add message.add_alternative(content_html, subtype='html')
I feel so dumb, it was right in front of me. Thank you