# Python Not Sending Email To Multiple Addresses

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I can't see where i'm going wrong with this, I hope someone can spot the problem. I'd like to send an email to multiple addresses; however, it only sends it to the first email address in the list and not both. Here's the code:

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP

recipients = ['example1@gmail.com', 'example2@example.com']

def send_email (message, status):
    fromaddr = 'from@gmail.com'
    toaddrs = ", ".join(recipients)
    server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('example_username', 'example_pw')
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, 'Subject: %s\r\n%s' % (status, message))
    server.quit()

 send_email("message","subject")
```

Has anyone came across this error before?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to add multiple receivers in Python SMTPlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729071/is-there-any-way-to-add-multiple-receivers-in-python-smtplib)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email to multiple recipients using python smtplib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856117/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-using-python-smtplib)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use this code, without your join:

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP

recipients = ['example1@gmail.com', 'example2@example.com']

def send_email (message, status):
    fromaddr = 'from@gmail.com'
    server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('example_username', 'example_pw')
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, recipients, 'Subject: %s\r\n%s' % (status, message))
    server.quit()

 send_email("message","subject")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

```
   import smtplib

   from email.mime.text import MIMEText

   s = smtplib.SMTP('xxx.xx')

   msg = MIMEText("""body""")
   sender = 'xx.xx.com'

   recipients = ['example1@gmail.com', 'example2@example.com']

   msg['Subject'] = "test"
   msg['From'] = sender
   msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
   s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
toaddrs = ", ".join(recipients)
```

to

```
toaddrs = recipients
```

since

```
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, ...)
```

expects `toaddrs` to be a *list* of email addresses. (Or, of course, just use `recipients` in place of `toaddrs`.)