# email is not delivered to multiple receivers using smtplib

Tags: email, smtplib

Code that I use to send an email.

```
def send_email(text, sender, receiver, sender_password, f):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["From"] = sender
    message["To"] = receiver
    message["Subject"] = "Model Pefromance Plot"

    attachment = MIMEApplication(open(f, "rb").read(), _subtype="html")
    attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", f"attachment; filename={f}")

    message.attach(attachment)

    text_message = text
    message.attach(MIMEText(text_message, "plain"))

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as server:
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender, sender_password)

        # Send the email
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
    print("Email sent successfully.")
```

I have a problem with sending an email to **multiple** recipients, the email is sent successfully (I can see it on the sender account). However, receivers do not receive the email, I checked the whole inbox. In case of only 1 receiver the program works fine and the email is delivered.

Examples:

- when `receiver = rec1@gmail.com`, program sends an email and this email can be delivered to receiver.
- when `receiver = rec1@gmail.com, rec2@gmail.com, rec3@gmail.com`, program sends an email, but this email cannot be delivered to receiver.

The only way how I can send an email to multiple users is by using a loop. In this case  an email will be sent to 1 recipient at a time. Very inconvenient, I want to send 1 email to multiple users at the same time.

I have tried this answer, [Is there any way to add multiple receivers in Python SMTPlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729071/is-there-any-way-to-add-multiple-receivers-in-python-smtplib), unfortunately it did not solve my problem.